# Sorting products with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to sort products using ajax but somehow the products won't get sorted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //sort in ajax
  $("#sort").on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var sort = $("#sort").val();
    var url = $(location).attr('href');

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        sort: sort,
        url: url
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.filter_raffles').html(data);
        console.log(sort, url);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

I tried to `console.log` the chosen sort and url, and it show those results.

[image]
[image]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Where is your sorting logic? All I can see is a string value named `sort`?

Comment: Your Ajax call has no handler. Check your browser console for error responses from the server.

Comment: presumably the sorting is done by the backend, the problem is that your `success` handler simply tries to dump the response into the HTML document, which since the response is (I presume) an object or array, will not work very well. (If it's an object you will see "[object Object]", if it's an array it's I assume an array of objects so you will see that several times with commas between.) You need to loop through or otherwise parse the data and get it to output actual HTML content.

Comment: `$('.filter_raffles').html(data);` implies that your back-end sort returns html.   What *exactly* is it returning?  `console.log(data)` would be a start, or look in the browser console.   But first things first - are you sure `$("#sort").on("change"...` is being called?  Can you see the request in the network tab?  Many issues we get on SO are like "my code does A,B,C but C doesn't work" when infact A doesn't work and it gets nowhere near C.  So convince us that it's getting that far.

Comment: hi, for the sorting logic i do that in the backend (controller) and i updated the result for `console.log(data)`